# Conditional probabilty joint distribution

Tags: probability

How do you find a conditional distribution of a discrete random variable which is in the form P(Y | X = x), e.g P(Y | X=5)? In my experience both discrete random variables have a value assigned to them in the case of conditional probability, like P(Y=1 | X=3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the intent of that form is to represent the entire probability mass function of the random variable $Y$ given a specific value of $X$.  Take for example, three dice which are numbered 1,2, and 3.  Die 1 is weighted so that the "number 1" has probability 1/3 and the remainder are equally likely.  Let's say die 2 has a different weighting, say "number 4" has 1/4 probability and the rest are equally likely.

Now, the actual probability distribution for $Y$, in this case being the number of dots showing, will depend on whether $X=1, 2, 3$, i.e. which of the three dice are selected.  You would then be able to calculate say the mean of $Y$ as $\Sigma Y P\left(Y|X=x\right)$ and so on once you know what X is.

I hope this helps.